# Select через js

Tags: javascript

```
<select class="form-control ship-input-dark input-sm" name="ik_cur" onkeyup="calculation();" onchange="calculation();">
                          <option value="USD">USD</option>
                          <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
                          <option value="RUB">RUB</option>
                          <option value="UAH">UAH</option>
                        </select>
<input type="hidden" value="" name="ik_am" id="ik_am">

$(function() {
$('.input').keyup(function(event) {
    $(event.currentTarget).val(function(i, old) {
        return NumberGetHumanReadable(old.replace(/[^[0-9]|\.]/g, ''));
    });     
});
$('#pay').submit(function() {
    $('.input').val(function(i, old) {
        return old.replace(/[^[0-9]|\.]/g, '');
    });
});
```

});

function calculation()
{

```
var amounts  = $("#amount").val().replace(/[^[0-9]|\,]/g, '');
    var ik_cur   = $("#ik_cur").val();
var ik_am    = 0;
if(ik_cur == 'USD')
    ik_am = amounts * 0.01128;
else if(ik_cur == 'EUR')
    ik_am = amounts * 0.0075371;
else if(ik_cur == 'RUB')
    ik_am = amounts * 0.3459003;
else if(ik_cur == 'UAH')
    ik_am = amounts * 0.1198562;

$("#ik_am").val(ik_am.toFixed(2));
```

}

Не понимаю поч ik_cur == 'EUR' не проканывает и всегда 0 получается(

Answer (score 2):

Могу предположить, потому, что вы ищете элемент с `id=ik_cur` вот здесь `var ik_cur   = $("#ik_cur").val();`
Но у вас нет элемента с таким `id`. У вас у `select` выставлен такой `name`, но не `id`.
Если хотите получить значение `select`, выставьте у него `id=ik_cur`